# node.js keep-alive web page

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js app which routes events to a web page's "shotbox" which is similar to a chatbox on the home page. This shoutbox requires a sessionVar and sessionId that changes based on your browser, session_id, and some other things. I have been successful in getting these variables from my browser, but if I close that browser page, my node.js app no longer works. I assume this has to do with a keep-alive header or something (i'm not sure, I don't know all that much about http to be honest). I want to have my node.js app be free from needing the browser up at all. I'm thinking I could, upon starting up the node.js app, login into the site, and retrieve these custom variables. But how do I achieve the same effect that the browser accomplishes when staying open?

Basically, how do I implement a keep-alive browser session in node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser session is supposed to end when you close it, that's expected behavior. Your app shouldn't care if anywhere between 0 - [huge number] of sessions are active at any given time; it sounds like something really basic is wrong with your server. Post some code...

Comment: Well, i guess i should have clarified that i'm using the browser's session variables in my node.js app. What i'm wanting to do is remove the need for a browser.

Comment: i was able to modify the shoutbox to allow for a generic "RESTFUL" request, so i don't need this anymore.